# Devexpress Gridview - Allow certain rows to be editable, not all

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have a gridview that can have records loaded from an XML file. Now when this list gets loaded into the gridview, there might be some records in there that have a child object say `Component` inserted as `new` (that do not exist in our DB, already).

Conditionally, in this gridview the users are not allowed to change any `field` of the child object `Component` **BUT** if we have a *newly* created child object from the list, we will allow the user to edit certain fields, such as `Carrier` & `Info`, of the child object.

My question is how to I allow editor to be shown in the grid for only certain rows, in this case rows with child object as `Component.Inserted = true`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go through below DevExpress thread:

[How to Conditionally Prevent Editing for Individual Grid Cells](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A249/how-to-conditionally-prevent-editing-for-individual-grid-cells)

The best approach to make a grid cell read-only based on a condition is to handle the [GridView.ShowingEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ShowingEditor.event) event and set the **e.Cancel** parameter to true when it is necessary to prevent editing.

Example:

```
// disable editing  
private void gridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {  
    GridView view = sender as GridView;  
    if(view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Region" && !USCanada(view, view.FocusedRowHandle))  
        e.Cancel = true;  
}
```

**References:**
[XtraGrid conditional edit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T257980/xtragrid-conditional-edit)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to handle `ShowingEditor` event of the gridview as following :

```
private void gridViewRecords_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //gets focused row and casts it into my object
    MyObject mo = (MyObject) gridViewRecords.GetRow(gridViewRecords.FocusedRowHandle);

    //check for my condition
    if(!(mo.Component.Inserted))
    {

          //intended cols, whose editor I want to block
          if(gridViewRecords.FocusedColumnName == "colCarrier"){
               e.Cancel = true;
          }
          else
          if(gridViewRecords.FocusedColumnName == "colInfo"){
               e.Cancel = true;
          }

    }
}
```